# Avaya ACR Search and Replay API : 401 Insufficient Rights

Tags: avaya

I am trying to play back a call using the Search and Replay API on Contact Recorder. I have set up the API user in the ACR Admin interface, giving it roles `"May use external API's, May export recordings as files"`. I have also given it rights to play back all recordings (`"000000-999999"`).

Using the HTTP request, it looks like my authentication is passing. When I use an incorrect password, I get `"401 Unauthorized"`, and when using the correct password, I get `"401 Insufficient rights"`.

Is there anyone that can give me a hint on where to look or roles that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution:

The actual problem was an incorrect INUM, although the server returned "insufficient rights".

I looked up a test INUM in the database, and tried testing with that. The correct way is to search for the INUM using the API, and then play back the recording using the details retrieved. Do not look up an INUM in the database and expect it to be retrievable through the API.

One possible reason might be that the INUM retrieved from the database might be a screen recording, or a segment of another recording, which is unplayable.